# Document Missing for android google cloud print

Tags: android, printing, google-cloud-print

I have a simple application in android. Which has two activity.One is Document.Activity with layout xml is butt.xml. And another one is PrintDialogActivity with print_dialog.xml. I share my printer and everything is ok.But When I select my share printer and click the print button in google cloud print, a black titlebar with "Document Missing" appear. Now what can I do? Please help me..

Here is my Document Activity:

```
public class Document extends Activity{

Button btnprt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.butt);

    btnprt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnprt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent printIntent = new Intent(Document.this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
                //File file = new File("/sdcard/StudentLatePass.txt");
                //printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/*");
                Uri docUri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
                //String ur = docUri.toString();
                printIntent.setDataAndType(docUri, "application/pdf");
                printIntent.putExtra("title", "StudentLatePass");
                startActivity(printIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is my butt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    android:text="Print" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my PrintDialogActivity:

```
 public class PrintDialogActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String PRINT_DIALOG_URL = "https://www.google.com/cloudprint     /dialog.html";
  private static final String JS_INTERFACE = "AndroidPrintDialog";
  private static final String CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING = "base64";

  private static final String ZXING_URL = "http://zxing.appspot.com";
  private static final int ZXING_SCAN_REQUEST = 65743;

  /**
   * Post message that is sent by Print Dialog web page when the printing dialog
   * needs to be closed.
   */
  private static final String CLOSE_POST_MESSAGE_NAME = "cp-dialog-on-close";

  /**
   * Web view element to show the printing dialog in.
   */
  private WebView dialogWebView;

  /**
   * Intent that started the action.
   */
  Intent cloudPrintIntent;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.print_dialog);
    dialogWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    cloudPrintIntent = this.getIntent();

    WebSettings settings = dialogWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    dialogWebView.setWebViewClient(new PrintDialogWebClient());
    dialogWebView.addJavascriptInterface(
      new PrintDialogJavaScriptInterface(), JS_INTERFACE);

    dialogWebView.loadUrl(PRINT_DIALOG_URL);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == ZXING_SCAN_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      dialogWebView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
    }
  }

  final class PrintDialogJavaScriptInterface {
    public String getType() {
      return cloudPrintIntent.getType();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
      return cloudPrintIntent.getExtras().getString("title");
    }

    public String getContent() {
      try {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        InputStream is = contentResolver.openInputStream(cloudPrintIntent.getData());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int n = is.read(buffer);
        while (n >= 0) {
          baos.write(buffer, 0, n);
          n = is.read(buffer);
        }
        is.close();
        baos.flush();

        return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return "";
    }

    public String getEncoding() {
      return CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING;
    }

    public void onPostMessage(String message) {
      if (message.startsWith(CLOSE_POST_MESSAGE_NAME)) {
        finish();
      }
    }
  }

  private final class PrintDialogWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      if (url.startsWith(ZXING_URL)) {
        Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        try {
          startActivityForResult(intentScan, ZXING_SCAN_REQUEST);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException error) {
          view.loadUrl(url);
        }
      } else {
        view.loadUrl(url);
      }
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      if (PRINT_DIALOG_URL.equals(url)) {
        // Submit print document.
        view.loadUrl("javascript:printDialog.setPrintDocument(printDialog.createPrintDocument("
          + "window." + JS_INTERFACE + ".getType(),window." + JS_INTERFACE + ".getTitle(),"
          + "window." + JS_INTERFACE + ".getContent(),window." + JS_INTERFACE + ".getEncoding()))");

        // Add post messages listener.
        view.loadUrl("javascript:window.addEventListener('message',"
            + "function(evt){window." + JS_INTERFACE + ".onPostMessage(evt.data)}, false)");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my print_dialog.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
 <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Is there anyone, who can help me????????????

Comment: I'm working against the same issue.  I'll let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: I wasn't able to print directly from something stored in assets or from a web URL turned into a Uri.

Comment: Look at the logs, for some reason the Uri isn't being parsed by the cloud print service.  I fixed mine by copying a file from assets to the cache directory and then using a File-based Uri from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the website content, copy the bitmap stream in the image form into the pdf. You can create a pdf in android using open source library. There are many libraries available to create pdf. Now you can print this pdf -

Uri docUri = Uri.parse(yourPDFFilePath); // give the path of you pdf file
 printIntent.setDataAndType(docUri, "application/pdf");

Its good to use pdf format for a printing document as Google Cloud Print service providers recommend to use it -
"We currently provide the best support for PDF documents, so we encourage you to use this format over others".

I tried this way & have succeeded in printing the webpage contents. Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Hi ,

did u try the same way or any other way? I am curious as the method which I followed makes use of addJavascriptInterface() & I am looking for some other way to avoid use of this method. 
(Actually, I want to make native android method calls for this print feature, but avoiding the use of addJavascriptInterface(). )

Comment: actually first time I take a screenshot of that webview and save it to in external storage then I added it to a pdf document(itext library) and last print that document with google cloud print. But I had a problem with that the screenshot can not give the full webview so I used webview.capturePicture().Where are you from?

Comment: Just webView.capturePicture() doesnt work with some image urls. As it shows dark black background with no contents. Try with droidText library for creating pdf document out of the bitmap . It works great. I am from India.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually if you do not use canvas then it shows dark black background with no contents. Do you know about exif data? How can I get that from a image? I am from Bangladesh.

Comment: sorry don't know about exif data !